# representation of teichmuller space Teichmuller space

Tags: riemann-surfaces

I want to study  representation of teichmuller space of surface of genus g in psl(2,R).
can you suggest any good references.

Comment: Do you mean "Description of Teichmuller space using representations of the surface group to $PSL(2,R)$"? If so, start with Abikoff's book. 

Comment: @Misha's guess is probably right, but the OP should pose a well-formed question before s/he expects to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

R. Fricke, F. Klein, Vorlesungen über die theorie der automorphen functionen, 1897-1912.